# ¿Cómo crear, con javadoc, la documentación de varias clases desde la linea de comandos (cmd)?

Tags: java, cmd, javadoc

En la terminal, para crear la documentación de una clase ejecuto:

```
C:\Users\JUAN CARLOS\Desktop\PracticasProgramacion\backup moodel\tictactoe_Carlos\tictactoe\ticTacToe1\src>javadoc -d .\doc\ MainTicTacToe.java
```

y funciona. Pero al intentar crear la documentación de varias clases ejecuto lo siguente y sale un error `javadoc: error - No packages or classes specified`

```
C:\Users\JUAN CARLOS\Desktop\PracticasProgramacion\backup moodel\tictactoe_Carlos\tictactoe\ticTacToe1>javadoc -verbose -d .\doc\*.java
javadoc: error - No packages or classes specified.
```

Antes lo ejecutaba así, pero ahora no lo permite, porque dice que tengo que especificar las clases. ¿Como puedo generar la documentación para varias clases?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el comando de windows `forfiles` que ejecuta un comando para un conjunto de archivos. Intenta lo siguiente, desde el mismo directorio que se ejecuta en la pregunta `.... \ticTacToe1\src` (porque las rutas proporcionadas son relativas)

```
forfiles /P .\ /M *.java /S /c "cmd /c javadoc -d .\doc\ @path"
```

Lo que hace el comando que propongo como solucion es:

- Enumerar los archivos en la ruta `.\` (que se da de manera relativa) que cumplan el comodín `*.java` y en todos los subdirectorios (opcion `/S`)
- Para cada uno de esos archivos ejecuta `javadoc -d .\doc\ @path` (donde @path es cada una de las rutas completas de los archivos enumerados)

La documentación de `forfiles` en el enlace https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles

Comment: Me vuelve a salir otro error es este `C:\Users\JUAN CARLOS\Desktop\PracticasProgramacion\backup moodel\tictactoe_Carlos\tictactoe\ticTacToe1\src>forfiles /P .\doc\ /M *.java /c "cmd \c javadoc -d .\doc\ @path"
ERROR: Files of type "*.java" not found.` Cuando hago dir me salen las propias clases del programa

Comment: Lo edité de nuevo para buscar recursivamente. Intenta de nuevo

Comment: Ahora si me ha funcionado muchas gracias por tu ayuda